# Suggestions for subjects about syntax

Tags: syntax

My professor asked us to do a presentation about syntax..and don't know which topic I should present...it'll be a 20 min. presentation.

I hope someone could help me with list of topics so I could choose.

Thank you.

........

So I've thought about grammatical case..
But my question is..What points should I talk about.

And thank you for all of your answers and suggestions.

Comment: That isn't really a question. You ought be be able to come up with topics on your own, and if one of them interests you, you can pose a question about the substance of the topic.

Comment: You could show that context-free grammars don't work for Latin, for example. 20 minutes is nothing so I guess you can only touch on a topic.

Comment: You still need to frame a question (so that you can *answer* the question in class). Here's an example: "In languages which mark case, do modifiers within the case-marked NP {always / ever} agree with the head noun in case?".

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have one suggestion for a topic: dependency vs. constituency. That is, you could present the basic distinction between approaches to syntax that assume dependency and approaches that assume constituency. This distinction is illustrated with the following trees that are taken from the article on dependency grammar in Wikipedia:

[image]

Actually, much of the information you need about the distinction is present in Wikipedia, in these articles among others:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_grammar

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrase_structure_grammar

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediate_constituent_analysis

More information is available in many of the links in these articles.

The reason why this is a good topic is that it's really important, and further, your professor may not be so aware of the distinction. My guess is that he/she does constituency grammar and has little awareness or knowledge of dependency grammar. This means that the topic would be good for your professor as well.

The ramifications of the dependency vs. constituency distinction are of course really big, but the core difference between dependency and constituency is rather simple, and it can fit nicely into a 20 minute presentation. If you'd like more information, contact me via email (tjo3ya@yahoo.com). I can provide the information you need in the form of good publications from Encyclopedias of Linguistics.

Comment: I realize you like dependency grammars, Tim, but I think that's way too complex for a first presentation. I'd suggest a review, with examples and handouts, of Levin's _English Verb Classes and Alternations_. It's atheoretical (aside from Levin's occasional habit of using "ergative" and "unergative" for English verbs), and it's full of lists and examples, plus a really extensive bibliography. Just the thing for a presentation.

Comment: @john lawler in exile, I don't think it is so complex, at least not at its most basic level. The distinction is captured quickly and easily by simply translating across trees: dependency --> constituency, and constituency --> dependency. Why are you in exile?

Comment: I'm in exile because I'm not allowed to log into my real account. The system doesn't recognize any of my passwords. Some system problem; I have it every time I travel and use a different computer. Last year I apparently travelled too much, because I'm permanently shut out.

Comment: @john lawler in exile. That's a problem, because of the significant reputation you had built up. Perhaps you don't care about that, but I think it's pertinent information to this site. The people with knowledge deserve the previleges that come with higher reputation scores. The scores provide one type of information about the quality of answers and comments.

Comment: @johnlawlerinexile If you can't access your old account, create a registered account (the one you currently have is "unregistered") and then you can send an email to SE asking to merge the two accounts (the newly created one and the old one). You will have everything back then.